# Display elements of an array one by one in order on event click

Tags: javascript

i want to show each item one by one on event click by order. By default it is the first element, when button is clicked it should show second one, after third etc...When it reaches the last element, it should repeat again and it should always show by order after click.

```js
var texts = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
btn.addEventListener("click", changeText);
var text = document.getElementById("myText");
text.innerHTML = texts[0];

function changeText(){

 for( var i = 0; i < texts.length; i++ ){
  text.innerHTML = texts[i];
 }
 return;
}
```

```html
<p id="myText"></p>
<button type="button" id="myBtn">Start</button>
```

Comment: when will it reach the end of the array, it has to show the first element?

Comment: @Loris yes, and it should never be stopped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fist of all you do not required to iterate all element of an array.If elements are in order then it can be achieve using index of the current element.We can get index of current element using **indexOf** method on an array. Below are the steps:

Step 1. Get index of current element using **indexOf** method on an array.

Step 2.Increment index by 1.

Step 3.Check if index is not the last index of array(in case of last index set index as 0).

Step 4.Get the element from array based on index and set in the document
element.

Here is my running code snippet:

```js
var texts = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
 var text=document.getElementById("myText");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
btn.addEventListener("click", changeText);
 text.innerHTML = texts[0];


    function changeText(){
       var searchTerm =  text.innerHTML  ;
       var index=texts.indexOf(searchTerm)+1;
       if(index == texts.length )index=0;
          var result=texts[index];
          text.innerHTML = result;
       return;
       }
```

```html
<p id="myText"></p>
<button type="button" id="myBtn">Start</button>
```

Comment: why, what? please add some explanation to you solution.

Answer (score 5):

You could omit the for loop, because it iterates to the end and the last item is shown.

Take a global variable `index` instead and increment and adjust by the length of the array to get only valid values of the array.

BTW, a single [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) statement at the end of the function without a different value than [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) is not necessary because in Javascript returns any function `undefined`, as long as it is not used as constructor (in connection with [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)). Then it is not necessary if the returned vaue is never used.

```js
var texts = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"],
    btn = document.getElementById("myBtn"),
    text = document.getElementById("myText"),
    index = 0;

btn.addEventListener("click", changeText);
text.innerHTML = texts[0];

function changeText() {
    index++;
    index %= texts.length
    text.innerHTML = texts[index];
}
```

```html
<p id="myText"></p>
<button type="button" id="myBtn">Start</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a prefect situation for iterator

```js
var texts = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
let iterator = textIterator(0);
function* textIterator(idx) {
  while(idx < texts.length) 
      yield idx++;
  iterator = textIterator(1);
  yield 0;
}


var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
btn.addEventListener("click", changeText);
var text = document.getElementById("myText");


function changeText(){
  text.innerHTML = texts[iterator.next().value]
}
```

```html
    <p id="myText"></p>
    <button type="button" id="myBtn">Start</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be this one:

```
function changeText() {
    text.push(text.innerHTML);
    text.innerHTML = texts.shift();
}
```

With push you insert the element showed in the div and with shift you remove the first element of the array and put it inside the div.

**Pro**: If the length of your array could change, you don't have to care about your index variable.

**Con**: Compared to an index variable, could be less performing

Answer (score 0):

I am going to provide two solution because in your question it is not clear that you all these output on one click or it should print on every click therefore i am going give both solution.

```
**This for printing all value in order on one click:** 



<p id="myText"></p>
     <button type="button" id="myBtn">Start</button>


var texts = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
btn.addEventListener("click", changeText);
var text = document.getElementById("myText");
text.innerHTML = texts[0];
var counter = 1;
 function changeText(){
       var len = texts.length;
       setInterval(function(){
       if(counter < len){
         console.log(texts[counter]);
         text.innerHTML = texts[counter];
         counter ++;
           }
     }, 500);
   }
```

```html
<p id="myText"></p>
<button type="button" id="myBtn">Start</button>
```

var counter = 1;

**This for printing the value in order on every click:**

```
var texts = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
btn.addEventListener("click", changeText);
var text = document.getElementById("myText");
text.innerHTML = texts[0];
var counter = 1;
function changeText(){
 var len = texts.length;
 if(counter < len){
   console.log(texts[counter]);
   text.innerHTML = texts[counter];
   counter ++;
 }
}
```